Power BI embedded analytics - SaaS application - fix column width of a matrix
The question I have is somewhat pedestrian in a regular Power BI Desktop.
However, I am working in a SaaS application that has an embedded Power BI component (Power BI embedded analytics).
This connects to a Microsoft Azure SQL Server database. I can always use just one single dataset, without calculated columns or measures; I cannot use DAX language either. I do not have Format option for my columns.
The dataset is essentially like a large table (or rather a view), developed using T-SQL language; it is called 'Report Columns'.
I now develop a simple matrix (sort of an Excel Pivot table) visual on my dataset in this embedded Power BI.
It is just a weekly time table report, where each of the 7 days in a given week, read employees schedule and job titles.
The dates are in columns, and the employee names in rows (the employee names are on the left side running vertically, but not shown in the the image file below).
The matrix changes its column width after each time I run the report.
I tried to use wrap text option, and disable Auto-Size.
Even after trying many solutions posted generally, I am not able to fix the column width of my matrix.
Any idea ?

Text wrapping of the Values part of my matrix is mandatory for my solution.
